# Verifying HMAC from Microsoft Teams custom Bot in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, bots, microsoft-teams

I am trying to authenticate a Microsoft Teams custom Bot with PHP, following the Microsoft [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/custom-bot) and read de C# example code.

> Microsoft Intructions steps:
>   1. Generate the hmac from the request body of the message. There are standard libraries on most platforms. Microsoft Teams uses standard
>   SHA256 HMAC cryptography. You will need to convert the body to a byte
>   array in UTF8.
>   2. To compute the hash, provide the byte array of the shared secret.
>   3. Convert the hash to a string using UTF8 encoding.
>   4. Compare the string value of the generated hash with the value provided in the HTTP request.

I had write a small php script to test this in local:

```
        <?php
        //Function to generate C# byte[] equivalent
        function unpak_str($val){
            $b = unpack('C*', $val);
            foreach ($b as $key => $value)
                $byte_a .= $value;

           return $byte_a;
          }

        //multi test outputs
        function hasher($values=[], &$output){
            //my secret share
            $secret="ejWiKHgsKY1ZfpJwJ+wIiN4+bgsFad/lkpu9/MWNXgM=";
            //diferent test
            $secret_64=base64_decode($secret);
            $secret_b=unpak_str($secret);
            $secret_b_64=unpak_str(base64_decode($secret));

            foreach($values as $msg){
                $hs = hash_hmac("sha256",$msg,$secret, true);
                $hs_64 = hash_hmac("sha256",$msg,$secret_64, true);
                $hs_b = hash_hmac("sha256",$msg,$secret_b, true);
                $hs_b_64 = hash_hmac("sha256",$msg,$secret_b_64, true);

                $output.=base64_encode($hs)." <BR>";
                $output.=base64_encode($hs_64)." <BR>";
                $output.=base64_encode($hs_b)." <BR>";
                $output.=base64_encode($hs_b_64)." <BR>";
             }
          }

    //Get data
    $data=file_get_contents('php://input');

    //real data request content for test
    $data ='{type":"message","id":"1512376018086","timestamp":"2017-12-04T08:26:58.237Z","localTimestamp":"2017-12-04T09:26:58.237+01:00","serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea-client-ss.msg/","channelId":"msteams","from":{"id":"29:1aq6GCrC6lM9dv3YkAYi1gxTPiLnojGFgVr0_Th-2x6DhqmHAOhFwQHFzSyDy5RruXY4_FZjJebKHU7bpxfHpXA","name":"ROBERTO ALONSO FERNANDEZ","aadObjectId":"1e0dc7a0-9d5e-488b-bcf2-7e39c84076b8"},"conversation":{"isGroup":true,"id":"19:9e1c52275dfb4d0b873ddf34eb9f4979@thread.skype;messageid=1512376018086","name":null},"recipient":null,"textFormat":"plain","attachmentLayout":null,"membersAdded":[],"membersRemoved":[],"topicName":null,"historyDisclosed":null,"locale":null,"text":"<at>PandoBot</at> fff","speak":null,"inputHint":null,"summary":null,"suggestedActions":null,"attachments":[{"contentType":"text/html","contentUrl":null,"content":"<div><span itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.skype.com/Mention\" itemid=\"0\">PandoBot</span> fff</div>","name":null,"thumbnailUrl":null}],"entities":[{"type":"clientInfo","locale":"es-ES","country":"ES","platform":"iOS"}],"channelData":{"teamsChannelId":"19:9e1c52275dfb4d0b873ddf34eb9f4979@thread.skype","teamsTeamId":"19:1e04f564ce5e4596bf2f266dbcff439e@thread.skype","channel":{"id":"19:9e1c52275dfb4d0b873ddf34eb9f4979@thread.skype"},"team":{"id":"19:1e04f564ce5e4596bf2f266dbcff439e@thread.skype"},"tenant":{"id":"9744600e-3e04-492e-baa1-25ec245c6f10"}},"action":null,"replyToId":null,"value":null,"name":null,"relatesTo":null,"code":null}';


    //generate HMAC hash with diferent $data formats
    $test = [$data, unpak_str($data), base64_encode($data), unpak_str(base64_encode($data))];
    hasher($test, $output);


    //microsoft provided HMAC
    $output.="<HR>EW2993goL1q7nGhytIb3jKmV6luXLz15Bq2aYwuCeiE="; 


    echo $output;
    /*
    Calculates: 
    0HsKoHza/QBvdz+nZw9tOti/eSWjyMMt/U77bfDqiE8=
    3jSq3I0HNQkjB9QfnnsxC1c3pF5PjqweHlSVcicrShY=
    bTQcGVTHX8/Gh4xovnN0WiJUiNaOQwvUZnwyFfiCaJE=
    qHBT2Y2ITyoxz2gmBbG8P1CrClvETus6dTffET3bAR8=
    8BcrXEQDDi77qgxCZLYyb/6ez8p9Qg2ZhTyZPWkdn/g=
    +8RSU5SSJKxqRLKkI+NkTE01xwu6PwPkKKMuvyyUvlo=
    PdL5ZpEwcN6Fe5kfX7zeAZLJvt0uLNTzu7lhuoOcr2o=
    s6M5pYruEgWeNMEOFfQRjVKQqtPBVaW3TJb2MzObF2c=
    xOTLhddbAwczQVneuTDQhPzmoIXGQljpf27c+hlhQII=
    aUMm5b2sKfmwGZOglfiu228fWqoLlwjc7z1QRdIbakE=
    5a7bAj9tzqhP9l85OvfVasURW0GSV5rykRutFFPO2fk=
    kwg6P2LoDL9rc3SSwJxQeoYJzZYlh+FHFefe38UokBM=
    eHeAzI7TV6vYDzxTxwyKWxMeVKFiFlIffWRiIMAk6fk=
    ZCyj2UppacQOTXogLPMFLDeMArQg03rhhlIwhynDvng=
    uQYK+7u9fppb62zXqtVYfkNK9wVawB3g+BlTyu4dc74=
    vjOFA3fqpwUx/VO9dQv3XviNhpjTNQsUwaJIwH4JjdY=
    ------------ MS PROVIDED HMAC ---------------
    EW2993goL1q7nGhytIb3jKmV6luXLz15Bq2aYwuCeiE=
     */
```

I've zero hash matching...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally after lots of trial, it maked me crazy and decided to start a new bot with a new secret. Now works fine. I'm human while MS Teams no... I suppos that was my fault with copy/paste but is a really stranger thing and the other hand old bot fails a lot of times with no response and the newest no

**Full example validation HMAC in PHP for Microsoft Teams Custom Bot:**

```
        <?php

        //The secret share with Microsoft Teams
        $secret="jond3021g9imMkrt8txF5AVPIwPFouNV/I72cQFii18=";

        //get headers
        $a = getallheaders();
        $provided_hmac=substr($a['Authorization'],5);

        //Get data from request
        $data=file_get_contents('php://input');

        //json decode into array
        $json=json_decode($data, true);

        //hashing
        $hash = hash_hmac("sha256",$data,base64_decode($secret), true);
        $calculated_hmac = base64_encode($hash);

        //start log var
        $log = "\n========".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."========\n".$provided_hmac."\n".$calculated_hmac."\n";

        try{
            //compare hashs
            if(!hash_equals($provided_hmac,$calculated_hmac))
                throw new Exception("No hash matching");
            //response text
            $txt="Hi {$json["from"]["name"]} welcome to your custom bot";
            echo '{
                "type": "message",
                "text": "'.$txt.'"
                 }';
            $log .= "Sended: {$txt}";
        }catch (Exception $e){
            $log .= $e->getMessage();
        }
        //write log
        $fp = fopen("log.txt","a");
        fwrite($fp, $log . PHP_EOL);
        fclose($fp);
```

Comment: 3 days is how long it took me to find this post!  thanks a TTTOOONNNN!!!.   question.  how can i see what the $data array/json consists of?   if user sends a body of text, how can i see what variable its in?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP expert, and your logic to cover all the cases is a bit convoluted, but I'm pretty sure your problem is that you aren't converting the message ($data) from UTF8 before computing the HMAC.

Here's a simple custom echo bot in Node that shows how to compute and validate the HMAC:

```js
const util = require('util');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const sharedSecret = "+ZaRRMC8+mpnfGaGsBOmkIFt98bttL5YQRq3p2tXgcE=";
const bufSecret = Buffer(sharedSecret, "base64");

var http = require('http');
var PORT = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 8080;

http.createServer(function(request, response) { 
    var payload = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        // console.log("Chunk size: %s bytes", data.length)
        payload += data;
    });

    request.on('end', function() {
        try {
            // Retrieve authorization HMAC information
            var auth = this.headers['authorization'];
            // Calculate HMAC on the message we've received using the shared secret         
            var msgBuf = Buffer.from(payload, 'utf8');
            var msgHash = "HMAC " + crypto.createHmac('sha256', bufSecret).update(msgBuf).digest("base64");
            console.log("Computed HMAC: " + msgHash);
            console.log("Received HMAC: " + auth);

            response.writeHead(200);
            if (msgHash === auth) {
                var receivedMsg = JSON.parse(payload);
                var responseMsg = '{ "type": "message", "text": "You typed: ' + receivedMsg.text + '" }';   
            } else {
                var responseMsg = '{ "type": "message", "text": "Error: message sender cannot be authenticated." }';
            }
            response.write(responseMsg);
            response.end();
        }
        catch (err) {
            response.writeHead(400);
            return response.end("Error: " + err + "\n" + err.stack);
        }
    });

}).listen(PORT);

console.log('Listening on port %s', PORT);
```

Comment: All content was in UTF-8. After your answer I tested it with `mb_detect_encodeing();` and the result was UTF-8.... Finally I think was a crazy problem with secret generation/copy. Thanks for help!

Comment: Great! I was wondering if there was perhaps a glitch with the secret but there was no evidence.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `unpack()`, or that `unpak_str()` function (which is also broken because it just overwrites each byte with the next one, not appending them).

Byte arrays are not a thing in PHP - the language doesn't have different string types; how strings are interpreted is entirely up to the functions using them. That is, your shared secret should be just the result of `base64_encode($secret)`.

Comment: Hi @Narf. Yes, It was my first option but I didn't get a match hash. I made de `hasher()` function to test multiple formats gived in `$test` Array and output four diferent `hash_hmac()` with and w/o unapck();