# Verifying HMAC from Microsoft Teams custom Bot in ColdFusion

Tags: php, coldfusion, chatbot, hmac, microsoft-teams

I am trying to authenticate a Microsoft Teams custom Bot with ColdFusion, [following the Microsoft instructions in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/outgoingwebhook).  I also tried following [this PHP example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47658513/3112803).  But I'm not having any luck.  Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
<cfset secretKey       = "MsVx7SpJKnSiycvsUyLMiD8lDIFkEUDhuYuFAT94hXY=">
<cfset httpRequestData = GetHttpRequestData()>
<cfset c               = httpRequestData.content>
<cfset calculated_hmac = toBase64(hmac(c, secretKey, "HMACSHA256"))>
```

I'm getting this...

```
calculated_hmac: NjE2RUY1RjREQTNEMzk1Q0RBNUJDMEE2NDhFNzk3RDIyNUMzRDJDMjk5NTYzMDgxODk0NkU3Njc3RTVEQTAyQQ==
```

While the headers.authorization from Microsoft is this...

```
HMAC 6N0WyOW7g+LqShKYsouWOrPjgh0PD1gazfwNeNwpuS8=
```

For this specific example the `GetHttpRequestData().content` was...

> {"type":"message","id":"1552059974228","timestamp":"2019-03-08T15:46:14.225Z","localTimestamp":"2019-03-08T09:46:14.225-06:00","serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/","channelId":"msteams","from":{"id":"29:1lY_4faAJwr1qSsIBSpFnI3nYpy3wv5hLp5qZk1_uuc_3ET_aW1Ttu_vN-evUZ0TXVKIBoy8wEBzPT7a1WgwOTQ","name":"Gordon
>   Frobenius","aadObjectId":"be3510a6-204d-4b3f-b6c3-52bbddb303d5"},"conversation":{"isGroup":true,"id":"19:a69ef3b3162a43018edb05db74138636@thread.skype;messageid=1552059031619","name":null,"conversationType":"channel"},"recipient":null,"textFormat":"plain","attachmentLayout":null,"membersAdded":[],"membersRemoved":[],"topicName":null,"historyDisclosed":null,"locale":"en-US","text":"cmpro
>   bot help\n","speak":null,"inputHint":null,"summary":null,"suggestedActions":null,"attachments":[{"contentType":"text/html","contentUrl":null,"content":"http://schema.skype.com/Mention\"
>   itemid=\"0\">cmpro
>   bot help\n","name":null,"thumbnailUrl":null}],"entities":[{"type":"clientInfo","locale":"en-US","country":"US","platform":"Windows"}],"channelData":{"teamsChannelId":"19:a69ef3b3162a43018edb05db74138636@thread.skype","teamsTeamId":"19:a69ef3b3162a43018edb05db74138636@thread.skype","channel":{"id":"19:a69ef3b3162a43018edb05db74138636@thread.skype"},"team":{"id":"19:a69ef3b3162a43018edb05db74138636@thread.skype"},"tenant":{"id":"0d78b7c2-75c2-4dad-966d-500250225e13"}},"action":null,"replyToId":null,"value":null,"name":null,"relatesTo":null,"code":null}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note, I couldn't reproduce that "calculated_hmac" because the sample "content" string must differ in some way from the original - probably just white space, but that's enough to totally alter the result ...).

Anyway, based on [the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/outgoingwebhook), I'd guess the main issue is using strings, instead of binary, in the hashing:

> 1. Generate the hmac from the request body of the message.... You will need to **convert the body to a byte array in UTF8.**
> 2. To compute the hash, provide **the byte array of the security token** provided by Microsoft Teams when you registered the outgoing webhook.

First try decoding the body into binary

```
<cfset bodyBinary = charsetDecode(GetHttpRequestData().content, "utf-8")>
```

Do the same with the secret key

```
<cfset secretKey  = "MsVx7SpJKnSiycvsUyLMiD8lDIFkEUDhuYuFAT94hXY=">
<cfset secretBinary = binaryDecode(secretKey, "base64")>
```

Lastly, don't forget HMAC() returns a hexadecimal string. If you need base64, you'll have to DIY:

```
<cfset hexHash = hmac(bodyBinary, secretBinary, "HMACSHA256")>
<cfset calculated_hmac = binaryEncode(binaryDecode(hexHash, "hex"), "base64")>
```

Comment: You're welcome.  I've always wondered why hmac doesn't support conversion to "base64" directly, but at least there's a way to get there...